# Creating a custom array

Tags: arrays, excel, validation

I'm trying to figure out a way to create custom arrays from a set of cells. To be more specific, I'm trying to make data validation criteria which allows only a list of values to be entered into the target cell.

But the list of allowable values are not in adjacent cells. So, I can't refer to them as, say, =$A$1:$A$6. I need to specify them as, say, = $A$1, $A$3, $A$6,.. etc. Please note that the intermediate cells contain values, hence, I can't use the option "Ignore Blank"

My idea is to create a custom array that contains only these cells and then enter that into the Data validation Criteria's "Source" selection box.

Is there a way I can achieve this in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a listbox to let the users select instead of enter the values themselves.

In excel, you can enable the developer tool and use the listbox.

In addition, if you know VBA programming, it is easier.

Hope that it gives you some direction

Comment: Same issue as before; I need to specify a contiguous set of cells, especially in a single column for the List box to work. But I want to specify any set of cells scattered across the sheet or file!